# I'm testing Agora.Io SDK in Unity3D, I cannot find how to select the input microphone GetAudioRecordingDeviceCount() is not working

Tags: agora.io

I'm trying to use Agora SDK, with Windows Build, but when I use the method:

```
IAudioRecordingDeviceManager recordingManager = mRtcEngine.GetAudioRecordingDeviceManager();
if (recordingManager == null) {
    Debug.LogError("recordingManager is null!");
    return;
}
int devices = recordingManager.GetAudioRecordingDeviceCount();
```

The result is -10000000
Then if I call for example:

```
int val = recordingManager.GetAudioRecordingDevice(index, ref name, ref deviceId);
```

I got val == -2
and name and deviceId are empty.

How can I enumerate the microphones and select one?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve that, you need to call CreateAAudioRecordingDeviceManager(), then you can call GetAudioRecordingDeviceCount()

(IF YOU ARE NOT USING IAudioRecordingDeviceManager, but AudioRecordingDeviceManager instead, looks like you need to call SetEngine() after instantiating AudioRecordingDeviceManager)

In my case, I am using both for audio and video like the following code below (AND IT WORKS FINE XD)

```
    //audio
    IAudioRecordingDeviceManager audioDevManager = mRtcEngine.GetAudioRecordingDeviceManager();
    audioDevManager.CreateAAudioRecordingDeviceManager();

    int audioDevCount = audioDevManager.GetAudioRecordingDeviceCount();
    Debug.Log($"AUDIO DEVICE COUNT: {audioDevCount}");


    //video
    IVideoDeviceManager videoDevManager = mRtcEngine.GetVideoDeviceManager();
    videoDevManager.CreateAVideoDeviceManager();
    
    int deviceCount = videoDevManager.GetVideoDeviceCount();
    Debug.Log($"VIDEO DEVICE COUNT: {deviceCount}");
```

p.s. mRtcEngine is a local variable that stores the return from IRtcEngine.GetEngine()